# How can I avoid that a CSS code doesn't applied globally

Tags: css

I need to use the following styling for a specific page on my website:

```
*::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #909090 !important;
}
```

But I don't want it to be applied to the whole site, but only to a specific page.
How can I achieve that with only CSS. (I cannot use Sass on this site, only CSS)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve your goal is to add an id to the body tag of your specific page. It's also a good idea to at least add the vendor-prefix for firefox as well.

The `*` isn't needed for the css selector to work by the way.

```css
#my-id ::-moz-placeholder, /* Firefox 19+ */
#my-id ::-webkit-input-placeholder /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
{ 
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body id="my-id">
  <form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="some@one.com">
  </form>
</body
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the parent element of your html a class name

Example:

html page:

```
<div class="page"></div>
```

css:

```
.page {*your styles*}
```

Comment: Can I do that with just CSS? Nesting?

Comment: @user1941537 you can, example: input[type="email"].big-dog::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: orange;
}

Comment: @user1941537 but then put the class there so: .page::-webkit-input-placeholder

Comment: That would be great. I'm going to test it out. Thanks.

Comment: @user1941537 np

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work.